# Jest - how to test if a component does not exist?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

How do I check if a component is not present, i.e. that a specific component has not been rendered?

Comment: Which renderer do you use, enzyme or the react test renderer?

Comment: I am using Enzyme.

Comment: Isn't it valid just check if an element from this component is on the screen?

Comment: Oops.. I mean, check if the element is NOT on the screen, by doing something like this: expect(component.find('ELEMENT').exists()).toBe(false);

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use enzymes [`contains`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/contains.html) to check if the component was rendered:

```
expect(component.contains(<ComponentName />)).toBe(false)
```

Comment: The `contains` call always returns `false` in my case. I used `expect(component.find('ComponentName').exists()).toBeFalsy();` instead as suggested by Periback.

Comment: @Samuel Your answer works for me. I'm curious why it needs to be "toBeFalsy()" not "toBe(false)". I understand the concept difference between those, however cannot understand why "toBe(false)" is not working in this case.

Comment: @shinyatk I believe the `find` and `exists` are the important parts. `toBe(false)` should work just fine. If you use [jest-enzyme matchers](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/tree/master/packages/jest-enzyme#tocontainmatchingelement), you can also just write `expect(component.find('ComponentName')).toExist()`

Comment: @Samuel Thank you for the prompt response. I will look into [jest-enzyme matchers](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/tree/master/packages/jest-enzyme#tocontainmatchingelement) and try with `toExist()` as well :)

Comment: @Samuel I believe this is becaus `contains` looks "inside" for the child components. If the component you're testing acts just like a wrapper that renders another component, you might not be able to find it

Comment: What if there are multiple components with same name? Like a list of items that is rendered by mapping an array?

Answer (score 111):

[`.contains`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/contains.html) receives a React Node or array of Nodes as an argument. Instead, use [`.find`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html):

```
expect(wrapper.find('selector').exists()).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: Nice succinct answer. How is this possible with react-testing-library?

Comment: Found it. For anyone interested, see my answer below.

Answer (score 22):

If you're using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#queryby) (I know the OP wasn't but I found this question via web search) then this will work:

```
expect(component.queryByText("Text I care about")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

You can query by `Text`, `Role`, and several others. See [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#queryby) for more info.

**Note:** `queryBy*` will return `null` if it is not found. If you use `getBy*` then it will error out for elements not found.

Answer (score 8):

Providing a slightly updated answer based on [the documentation for enzyme-matchers's `toExist`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/blob/master/packages/jest-enzyme/README.md#toexist). This will require you to install the `enzyme-matchers` package.

```
function Fixture() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span className="foo" />
      <span className="bar baz" />
    </div>
  );
}

const wrapper = mount(<Fixture />); // mount/render/shallow when applicable

expect(wrapper.find('span')).toExist();
expect(wrapper.find('ul')).not.toExist();
```

Comment: This requires `enzyme-matchers` this library. https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers

Comment: @smbl This is true.  I would hope for most projects, adding a dev dependency for easier testing isn't going to be too much of a problem.

Answer (score 5):

`.contains` does not expect a selector, unlike find.  You can look at the length attribute of the ShallowWrapper

`expect(wrapper.find('...')).toHaveLength(0)`

I found I needed to use this syntax with Enzyme and Jest to test if a Connected Component existed in the rendered output.

Comment: I think this might be a bit misleading. When we see something with `length` property, we might expect this to be Array or smth. IMO `exists` helps to distinguish these cases more swiftly.

Answer (score 3):

We use Jest and Enzyme, and I've found the only good test is to import the sub-component and test this way:

```
expect(component.find(SubComponent).length).toEqual(0); // or (1) for exists, obvs
```

I tried all the other answers and none worked reliably.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was rendered then removed later. I needed to wait for it to disappear (because it was hidden by a button):

```
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(screen.queryByText('some text')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-testing-library, then this also will work:

```
expect(component.queryByText("Text I care about").toBeNull());
expect(within(component).queryByText("Text I care about")).toBeNull();
```

Note: In my case, I needed to use `queryBy*` because it doesn´t error out when the text element (that contains the text: Text I care about) does not exist. Therefore, I could evaluate whether there is an existence of a text component or not.