# Jest/Enzyme - TypeError: div.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Below is a a little test file that I made for a React project that is using both Jest and Enzyme for testing. In this test, I'm simply trying to find an element in the component and see that it exists (as a truthy conditional). The whole point of this test wasn't just to see if the element existed, but I figured I'd start here. I'm very new to testing, so this syntax/implementation may be bonkers:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import HamburgerIcon from './HamburgerIcon';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('my first test -- will add better text here later', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<HamburgerIcon />, div);

  expect(div.find('.closed').exists()).toBeTruthy();

  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

Running this results in this error:

> TypeError: div.find is not a function

I originally built this test after seeing [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810583/7386637).

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, but I'm guessing that maybe I haven't properly "mounted" the component in this test? In the same Stack Overflow thread from the previous link, [this answer shows how you would mount a component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54406136/7386637), but another comment on that answer says that another package needs to be installed in order to do that.

I sort of figured that using the `div` variable as the container to be searched with `find` would work, but am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: `.find` is a jquery method and not native to javascript

Comment: You need to follow proper guide instead of jumping off stackoverflow answers. You are in wrong direction. You are missing mounting or shallow rendering in your code and on which you run `.find` ReactDOM is not test renderer, enzyme is in your case

Comment: [`.find` is in the Enzyme API](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) -- I would think that importing enzyme would include `.find`, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: After looking at the other SO post, theyre using `.find` on a react component, not on a native javascript element object. So you would need `expect(Component1.find(<Component2 />).exists()).toBeTruthy();`

Comment: @Rikin thanks -- I will look into mounting and how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sample code for you, may not be 100% what you need but should get you started. I also included `console.log` so that you know what gets rendered.

To explain a bit on what happens, is in your test case you are calling `shallow` method and passing your React component to it to render. Test cases are run in virtual browser/renderer not the real browser (unless you configure it that way).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import HamburgerIcon from './HamburgerIcon';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('my first test -- will add better text here later', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<HamburgerIcon />);
  console.log(wrapper);
  expect(wrapper.find('.closed').exists()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Thanks , that passes! I'll look into how this works.

Comment: I also saw this earlier when I was looking things up -- haven't read it all the way through, but figured I'd share it -- https://kentcdodds.com/blog/why-i-never-use-shallow-rendering -- not sure if you have any thoughts on this! In any case, I'll be looking into enzyme's `shallow` and `mount` more.

Comment: Depends on need I would say. But check out his library `react-testing-library` easier to get along and play with it. You dont need Enzyme in that case.